# Cannot connect to Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been connecting just fine with my ec2 instance ad suddenly today when I tried connecting i get  "connection refused".  My security setting for ssh is set to all, and I have also set it to my specific IP address for good measure.  Please can someone advise? I have also tried rebooting the system from the console.

Comment: Are you connecting using elastic ip or public dns? Can you share the exact configuration done in security group of this ec2 instance.

Comment: Were able to resolve the issue you're having? @Nans troubleshooting appears to be spot on. Let us know please.